# Buying a new house; lender asking for my friend’s bank account statements

Tags: loans

I am buying a new house. I borrowed $5k from a friend to use for the ‘earnest money deposit’. Now the agent for the 
mortgage company  tells me that they demand to see my friend’s bank statements for two months. Is that normal or is that exceptional? Has anybody experienced anything similar?

Comment: You involved your friend in the transaction, so of course that is normal.  Why would you do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I borrowed $5k from a friend to use for the ‘earnest money deposit’.

That earnest money  deposit is made by the buyer into an escrow account to take the home off the market while the rest of the financing is being obtained.

If the deal is completed that money is available to be used as part of the down payment or closing costs at settlement. But if the buyer has to break the contract that money is forfeited according to the terms specified in the contract.

The lender is concerned that you had to borrow the earnest money deposit.

If you really did borrow the money they may require the friend to become a co-borrower/co-owner, which will require significant financial paperwork. If it was a gift they will want that documented, and will require your friend to sign paperwork stating it is a gift that you never have to pay back.

When a lender wants to see bank statements for a few months they are looking for sources of deposits. They will see paychecks, and they will want to know about other deposits to understand if the source of the earnest money deposit was a loan or gift from somebody else.